# Multiple name servers on the same server

Tags: windows, dns, hosting, vps

I have setup my name servers on my VPS to handle hosting of websites and emails.

This is my scenario.

ns1.domain.com ======= xx.xx.xx.xx   (Shared / public IP) 
ns2.domain.com ======= xx.xx.yy.yyyy (Static IP)

I need to know if one IP fails or is unreachable, would the second IP also fail?

---

Another issue I'm facing is when I created my previous master DNS, it was setup as follows.

ns1.domain1.com ====== xx.xx.xx.xx (Shared / public IP) 
ns2.domain1.com ====== xx.xx.xx.xx (Shared / public IP)

Both were using the same IP.  But now If I try to update the secondary DNS IP with a newly installed static IP.  It does not want to resolve to the new IP. It keeps resolving to the public IP.

I am using Windows Server 2012.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I been pulling my hair out since last week with DNS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both IP's on the server are configured on the same Network Adapter, then if 1 fails, the other would fail as well.

I also found that my ISP configured the 1st IP incorrectly, which was causing more timeouts than the second IP I had installed.

I eventually setup a 2nd server to provide secondary DNS backup.

In conclusion. You can have 1 server setup to handle both primary and secondary DNS, as long as both IP's are configured on separate Network Cards. If you are not happy with that, then just get a 2nd server to handle secondary DNS.  The 2nd server can also act as a backup for other data, if you are trying to minimize costs and utilize all of your resources available without creating extra costs.

I hope this can provide some information to others in future.